# Symfony2 OneToOne annotation inserting/updating related entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, one-to-one

I have Product entity related to Settings entity with one-to-one relation. All products are imported and Product don't have related row in Setting table at start.

When updating the product using Symfony proper relation is created so I have OneToOne between Product and Setting. This is done using simple INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO settings (id_product, setting_1, setting_3, setting_3) VALUES (11153, '0', '1', '1');
```

This insert is made automaticaly by Symfony thanks to annotations and method:

```
$em->merge($product);
$em->flush();
```

Unfortunately when I try to update product next time another insert to setting table is done and obviously I have and error becouse id_product is PK and have to be unique. What should I do to force Symfony to do an UPDATE instead of INSERT if there is a relation between Product and Setting? I create my music using the newest version of Symfony.

Comment: Can you post the code on how you are updating your settings entity? Normally, $product->getSetting()->setSomeVar('foobar') ought to update the setting entity rather than create a new one...

Comment: I post it - look at merge method. When it's reached it's automaticaly updating (always new insert - the problem) Setting entity thanks to annotations...

Comment: I still think we need more information on annotations, cascades, use of merge v persist etc. IME, I've only used merge to manage entities which have become detached from the entity manager. What happens if you use persist() instead of merge()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update is not done in the same way that you would create an entity. Here is a very quick example (you'd have to handle a few exceptions etc.. but code is 'short' to show you the differences:

<kbd>1</kbd> When your create a Task, you create a new entity Task and save it to the database

<kbd>2</kbd> When you update a Task, you first fetch that task from the database and then save it to the database.

**Create:**

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        // create a task and give it some dummy data for this example
        $task = new Task();
        $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
        $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
            ->add('task', 'text')
            ->add('dueDate', 'date')
            ->add('save', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->bind($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {

                // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($task);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
             }  
        } 

        return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

**Update :**

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $taskId)
    {
        // get the task
        $task = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AcmeTaskBundle:Task');
            ->find($taskId);

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
            ->add('task', 'text')
            ->add('dueDate', 'date')
            ->add('save', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->bind($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {

                // update the task
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
             }  
        } 

        return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

I'd recommend that you check out:

- [Databases and Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/doctrine.html)
- [Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/forms.html)

Comment: I will test it later today. The problem is that Product entity exist in DB and Setting not at start... Looks like I have to implement some logics to handle this.